# Google Dialogflow welcome intent

Tags: slack-api, chatbot, dialogflow-es

Is it possible for Dialogflow to send a default welcome message to the user, without needing him to say anything? We are building a slack based bot and we have tried the default welcome intent. But even that doesn't send anything back to the user when he adds the slack bot. He doesn't know what to do after the bot is added.

Answer (score 0):

try SLACK_WELCOME event in the default welcome intent

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question we have tried the default welcome intent. Slack's as well. But it isn't sending anything to the user when the bot is added. Only responds to queries. Have you done something similar in the past?

Comment: I actually tried for facebook it worked but i haven't tried for slack

Comment: I think it works on Facebook through a Get started button. isn't it?

Comment: did u ever find a way to it?